# How to extract the user's facebook status including the "How are you feeling ?" part, programatically using facebook's graph api or any other methods?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to extract the User's status update including the mood of the user which uses the new feature of facebook's status updates i.e "what you are doing? "

for example : Test status update. Feeling happy

Is it possible to extract this using the graph api or any other method where i could get the timeline of the user and  the html file for the mood of the user.

Answer (score 0):

You need to request the read_stream permission and then call /me/feed. However, that API doesn't currently return the extra data around "feeling happy" etc.