# How to get Facebook feeling (smilies) in your IOS App (xcode)?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have written an IOS App to retrieve data from the Facebook account from the user's phone.  I can retrieve data like Name, Profilepicture, ... (after the user logged in with his Facebook account details).

I cannot retrieve the status of the user, more specifically the feelings (smilies) posted, like: "Feeling good", "Feeling proud", ...

I have tried the following code:

```
self.userprofilePicture.profileID = user.objectID;    // works fine
self.userUsername.text = user.first_name;             // works fine
self.userEmail.text = [user objectForKey:@"email”];   // works fine
self.userStatus.text = [result objectForKey:@"status"];  // no result
```

I have also tried the following:

```
if ([user objectForKey:@"status"]) {
    NSArray *temp = [user objectForKey:@"status"];
    for (int i = 0; i < [temp count]; i++) {
            self.userStatus.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@“User Status: %d, %@", i, self.temp];
        }
    }
```

Is it possible to retrieve the "feelings" information from Facebook?

Comment: Looks like it's not possible at the moment. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23424809/how-to-extract-the-users-facebook-status-including-the-how-are-you-feeling

Comment: That's too bad.  I had searched already a lot before asking the question here, so I was kind of expecting the answer.  Thanks !

Comment: It would be a nice feature though, so other App's could use it for better advertising for example.  Do you know if there is any chance that this would be added in the future?  I have read articles about it where it is stated that this status could be used (in the future?) exactly for these purposes.